# Elementor kit installation problem on WordPress

Tags: php, wordpress, elementor

when I am going to install elementor kit om wordpress show this PHP problem. what can I do now?

Template Kit Install Error
There was an issue installing this template kit. Please try again.

PHP Zip extension not loaded

{
"error": {
"context": "installTemplateKit",
"code": "zip_failure",
"message": "PHP Zip extension not loaded",
"data": []
}
}

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

You need to tell your hosting provider to enable the PHP Zip extension. Also, some hosting panels (Directamin, Cpanel) can be activated.